# Totals on Group For SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to build an SSRS report that Groups on the fields "Process" "Division" and "Item ID"
[image: Groupings]
What Id like to do is add a total line under ITem Id, but when I do, it totals for the division instead of each individual ID.
For instance id like it to look like

```
ITEM ID
12345  100.00
12345  100.00
12345  200.00
TOTAL  400.00

54321  100.00
TOTAL  100.00
```

But instead, as I say, it totals on Division, ignoring the ITEM ID group:
[image]

I went under the Item ID group and did an add total, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

When I added the group, I checked on it to have a footer and it started grouping the way I wanted it to.